# python application changing logging level

Tags: python, database, logging

I have a python package and the logging level is set as below (in app.py).

```
logger = logging.getLogger('app')
logger.handlers = []
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

I generally import this module DbApp (from app.py) and directly run it. As this package is installed using pip, I don't want to change the logging level in the file.

How can I change from my main program to set the logging level?

```
from db.rest import DbApp    
app = DbApp()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set the logging level dynamically using the setLevel API.
As an example: logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

For further info, you may refer to : https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Hope it helps.